# Laravel Relation Many to Many

Tags: laravel, relationship

I'm using laravel and sentinel (Sentry) that default using users, groups, and users_groups database table

```
users
-----------------
id         name
1          user
2          user
3          admin


groups
-------------------
id           name
1            Users
2            Admins

users_groups
--------------------
user_id      group_id
1            1
2            1
3            1
3            2
```

i define the relation on laravel model and it's work fine when i try to print

```
$users = Group::find($id)->user;
```

but how to print just user only?

```
$users = Group::where(array("name"=>"Users"))->get()->user;
```

it's still show all data include the admins, i just want to show user only, how to do this?

i know the problem because at users_groups table admin have Users id too..

Please someone help me. It's verry confusing

Answer (score 2):

You can use `with` to get the data of specified relation as below :

```
$users = Group::with('user')->find($id);
```

This will return data of group with user.

If you just want a data of only user table you have to change the query and rather than using model `Group` you have need to query on `User` model something like below:

```
$users = User::where('group_id', $groupId);
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships
http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_with

Comment: it's not working, because there is also admin that can act as user too, i i  query using where group_id = user, then the admin is selected too